# C# - Verifying Issuer in a multi-tenant app

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, azure-ad-msal

I have a web api built in .Net framework that validates the token before giving access to the controllers.

I am using OWIN middleware to use JWT Bearer Authentication.

```
var tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The web app and the service are sharing the same clientId
            ValidAudience = clientId,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        };

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")),
        });
```

I had to set ValidateIssuer to false because I don't know from which tenant the user is signing in.

So does this mean I should not put any check on issuer? What should I do after this and How?

I got the above source code from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-api).

Answer (score 0):

Although for ASP.NET Web App [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp-v1#configure-sign-in-options) may help you to decide what to do: if your intent is to restrict given tenants to use your Web API, then you can also use the *ValidIssuers* parameter - if your API is open to any organization that has Azure AD to use, then you should only set the *ValidateIssuer* to false.